# Is there any way to create contract by binary data?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

In solidity, if we have defined contracts already, its simple to create an contract in contract by using the keyword: `new`, like this:

```
contract FatherContract {
    function createChild() public {        
        new ChildContract();
    }
}

contract ChildContract {
    constructor() public {
        //...
    }
}
```

but what if I want to create an contract from binary data, like this:

```
contract FatherContract {
    function createChild(bytes contractDataInfo) public {        
        // any way to create a new contract in this method 
        // using contractDataInfo?
    }
}
```

If the `contractDataInfo` is contract creation info, any way to create a new contract in method `createChild`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you have to write just a little bit of assembly:

```
bytes memory bytecode = contractDataInfo; // need to copy into memory
address addr;
uint256 value = 0; // change if you want to attach ether

assembly {
    addr := create(value, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode))
}

require(addr != 0, "Contract creation failed.");
```